# Unity Get Last Name

Tags: facebook, get, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

Im having trouble getting the user's last name. I can get the first name just fine. 
But profile["last_name"] and profile["name"] arent working for me.

Please help!

```
void APICallback(FBResult result)
{
    //FbDebug.Log("APICallback");
    if (result.Error != null)
    {
        // Let's just try again
        FB.API("/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,friends.limit(100).fields(first_name,last_name,id)", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, APICallback);
        return;
    }

    profile = Util.DeserializeJSONProfile(result.Text);
    name = profile["first_name"];
    fullname = string.Format("{0} {1}", profile["first_name"], profile["last_name"]);
}
```

Comment: Having the same problem. Can't find an answer. Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

You might be using Facebook Unity SDK sample codes - [Util.cs](https://github.com/fbsamples/friendsmash-unity/blob/master/friendsmash_start/Assets/Scripts/Util.cs#L37). In the code, 
`Util.DeserializeJSONProfile` returns a dictionary including only `first_name`.

You can fix the function in this way:

```cs
public static Dictionary<string, string> DeserializeJSONProfile(string response)
{
    var responseObject = Json.Deserialize(response) as Dictionary<string, object>;
    object nameH;
    var profile = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    if (responseObject.TryGetValue("first_name", out nameH))
    {
        profile["first_name"] = (string)nameH;
    }
    if (responseObject.TryGetValue("last_name", out nameH))
    {
        profile["last_name"] = (string)nameH;
    }
    return profile;
}
```